# What is the inverse of ImageList.RemoveAt(index1);?

Tags: c#, list

I tried many times to resolve this case but I always get an error because it's an Image in an ImageList. What code do I need to literally `re-add` the removed Image from the list. This is my code (The final line doesn't work).

```
int index9 = random.Next(0, normalCards1.Count - 1);
pictureBox9.Image = normalCards1[index9];
normalCards1.RemoveAt(index9);
...
normalCards1.Insert(index9);
```

Comment: "doesn't work" is bad explanation. Since you should be getting compile error you should add it to the post.

Comment: Side note: Assuming you trying to write deck shuffling - check out implemetations provided in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273313/randomize-a-listt-in-c-sharp/1262619#1262619

Comment: Please also clarify what `ImageList.RemoveAt` refers to because `ImageList` class does not have `RemoveAt` method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to pass `T item` as well with index.

you can add it back this way:

```
normalCards1.Insert(index9,pictureBox9.Image);
```

See [**List.Insert Method  MSDN docs here**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sey5k5z4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

[ImageListCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imagelist.imagecollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is the type of [ImageList.Images](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imagelist.images%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does not provide a way to insert items by index.

If you want to shuffle or somehow else reorder images you need to remove them all and add them again after reordering. I.e. adding all images to a `List<T>`, sort, and use [AddRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imagelist.imagecollection.addrange%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

You can also try using indexed access (`imageList.Images[3] = ...` ) to swap items.